# Type For fetched Data from Github APi

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const url = "https://api.github.com/users";

interface IFetchData {}

const FetchData = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchdata = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const users = await response.json();
        setUsers(users);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("errs", err);
      }
    };
    fetchdata();
  }, []);
  return (
    <section>
      <h3>GitHUb Users</h3>
      <ul className="users">
        {users.map((user) => {
          const { id, avatar_url, login, html_url } = user;
          return (
            <li key={id}>
              <img src={avatar_url} alt={login} />
              <div>
                <h5>{login}</h5>
                <a href={html_url}>Profile</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
};
export default FetchData;
```

Returned Data From API

```
avatar_url: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=4"
​
events_url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}"
​
followers_url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers"
​
following_url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}"
​
gists_url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}"
​
gravatar_id: ""
​
html_url: "https://github.com/mojombo"
​
id: 1
​
login: "mojombo"
​
node_id: "MDQ6VXNlcjE="
​
organizations_url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs"
​
received_events_url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events"
​
repos_url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos"
​
site_admin: false
​
starred_url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}"
​
subscriptions_url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions"
​
type: "User"
​
url: "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

What Type should I give to **useState**, as I only need 3-4 properties out of all the properties. Do I need to create a Interface or Type taking in all the Properties or can I somehow give some Generic Type? Is it Preferable to leave useState empty if I am not sure of the Data? I tried giving it some Generic Value like **<T[]>**, but that did not work.

Comment: You might want to look into Octokit,  it has types built in. https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v19#users-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is user interface type with fixed error.

Check this link run this code. [Solution link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-mppvx8?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1071)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const url = "https://api.github.com/users";

interface UserType {
  id: string | number;
  avatar_url: string;
  login: string;
  html_url: string;
}

const FetchData = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<UserType[]>([]);

  const fetchdata = async () => {
    try {
      const users: UserType[] = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
      if (Array.isArray(users)) {
        setUsers(users);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("errs", err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchdata();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <h3>GitHUb Users</h3>
      <ul className="users">
        {users.map((user) => {
          const { id, avatar_url, login, html_url } = user;
          return (
            <li key={id}>
              <img src={avatar_url} alt={login} />
              <div>
                <h5>{login}</h5>
                <a href={html_url}>Profile</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
};
export default FetchData;
```

Comment: Hi @Sagar, thankyou for responding. 
The interface that you defined is having just some Properties, but when we use setUser we are passing an object with few extra properties, won't the compiler will through an error ?